# Code Igniter Model gives an unexpected error

Tags: codeigniter, model

This is my controller:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function insert1(){
        $this->load->model("test1");

        $newRow = ["name" => "bob",
            "id" => 123 ,
            ];

        $this->test1->insert_entry($newRow);
     }
}
```

I have this code for my model:

```
class Test1 extends CI_Model {

    function insert_entry($array){   

        $this->db->insert("TEST",$array);​
    }
}
```

and it gives me this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\ilink-site\application\models\test1.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 0):

remove comma after 123 at that line `"id" => 123 ,`

Answer (score 0):

There is in array defining.
$array = array('key'=> 'value');

`class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function insert1(){
        $this->load->model("test1");
        $newRow = array("name" => "bob", "id" => 123);
        $this->test1->insert_entry($newRow);
     }
}`